# Numeros amigos, problema

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, pgadmin

tengo un problema con los números amigos. En mi código he conseguido mostrar que poniendo los números que queramos nos diga si son amigos o no lo son.

El ejej tiene que calcular si num1 y num2 son números amigos. Un número A se dice amigo de B si la suma de todos los divisores propios (los divisores de un número N sin incluir al propio N) de A equivale a B, así como la suma de todos los divisores propios de B equivale a A.

Por ejemplo: 220 y 284 son números amigos, ya que:

Los divisores propios de 220 son 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 y 110, que sumados dan 284.

Los divisores propios de 284 son 1, 2, 4, 71 y 142, que sumados dan 220.

El problema esta en que no se meter los divisores de los dos números para comprobar que la suma de los divisores den ese numero. Alguien podría aconsejarme? Muchas gracias

```
    DO $numeros_amigos$
    DECLARE
    num1 INTEGER :=220;
    num2 INTEGER :=284;
    i INTEGER :=1;
    suma1 INTEGER :=0;
    suma2 INTEGER :=0;
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN i..num1 LOOP
        IF num1%i=0 AND i!=num1 THEN
          suma1=suma1+i;
          CONTINUE;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      FOR i IN i..num2 LOOP
        IF num2%i=0 AND i!=num2 THEN
          suma2=suma2+i;
          CONTINUE;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      IF suma1=num2 AND suma2=num1 THEN
         RAISE NOTICE 'Los numeros % y % son numeros amigos', num1, num2;
      ELSE 
         RAISE NOTICE 'Los numeros % y % son numeros enemigos', num1, num2;
      END IF;
    END $numeros_amigos$;
```

Comment: Usas pgadmin y mysql? (Eso dicen las etiquetas de la pregunta). Igual, pgAdmin es irrelevante y en cambio, es importante que especifiques qué base de datos estás usando

Comment: @David te doy la bienvenida al sitio, además de lo que te han dicho, te recomiendo que expliques qué es un número amigo, así tendrás más posibilidades de que una persona que sepa mucho de SQL pero que no sepa lo que es ese término matemático te pueda ayudar.

Comment: De acuerdo, aun no estoy muy familizarizado con esto. Gracias a los dos por el comentario

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué no hacer operaciones de SQL en vez de usar programación procedural? Dejo un ejemplo que solo habría que cambiar las literales por variables.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( SELECT SUM( id) FROM tally
                  WHERE MOD(220, id) = 0
                  AND id < 220) = 285 
             AND ( SELECT SUM( id) FROM tally
                  WHERE MOD(285, id) = 0
                  AND id < 285) = 220 
             THEN 'Numeros Amigos' 
             ELSE 'Numeros Enemigos' END AS resultado;
```

La solución usa una tabla de números (llamada tally en inglés) que permite evitar los bucles. Aquí dejo como crear una que va de 1 a 1000.

```
CREATE TABLE tally (
    id int unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tally (id) 
SELECT x.n * 100 + y.n * 10 + z.n + 1
FROM (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9)x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9)y
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9)z
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo no entiendo a qué te refieres cuando dices "El problema esta en que no se meter los divisores de los dos números". No entiendo meterlos dónde? Con acumularlos basta. Eso está bien.

Lo que yo de ti cambiaría son un par de cosas:

1. Quita el if del interior de los bucles, poniendo un FOR i IN 1..num1-1
2. Quita las instrucciones continue, que no sirven de nada.

En fin, el código que muestras funciona, no?

Comment: Porque me pide que aparte muestre los divisores de cada numero introducido, que eso es lo que no sabria hacer. El codigo funciona y muestra si el numero es amigo o no

Comment: Gracias por las notas voy a probarlas